# Django : "break" a class based view with intermediate "return render" won't work

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

I use a CB ListView for displaying objects. I want to add a session variable based on another models' PK during the execution of my ListView:

**views.py**

```
class ProduitListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):

    model = Produit
    context_object_name = "produits"
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = 'products/produits.html'
    ordering = ['-mageid', ]

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProduitListView, self).get_context_data(
            *args, **kwargs)

        # used for incoming products (sourcing cf URLS)
        supplier_pk = self.kwargs.get('pk', None)
        if supplier_pk:
            set_incoming_supplier(self.request, supplier_pk)

        context['avail_warehouses'] = Warehouse.objects.all()
        context['js_warehouses'] = serialize(
            'json', Warehouse.objects.all(), fields=('code', 'id', ))
        context['title'] = 'Produits'
        return context
```

**set_incoming_supplier (in another APP)**

```
@login_required
def set_incoming_supplier(request, pk):
    supplier = Supplier.objects.filter(pk=pk).first()
    supp = SupplierSerializer(instance=supplier).data
    rs = request.session
    if 'income' in rs:
        if 'cur_supplier' in rs['income']:
            prev_supplier = rs['income']['cur_supplier']
            if supp != prev_supplier:
                return render(request, 'sourcing/alert_supplier_change.html',
                              {'prev_supplier': prev_supplier, 'cur_supplier': rs['income']['cur_supplier']})
    rs['income'] = {'cur_supplier': supp}
```

I thought the `return render(request, 'sourcing/alert_supplier_change...` could "break" my ListView and render my `alert page` but it doesn't. ListView seems to continue and finally renders my `ProduitListView` page.

Why doesn't this work ?

Comment: You seem to have a misconception of how the `render` function works. It is just a shortcut function which returns a `HttpResponse` object with a rendered template, the handler that Django has then uses this object to send the response to the client.

Comment: I've used render hundreds times without knowing exactly how it works. I especially use it for sending (context) forms and objects. I thought I could use it to achieve my goal but visibly, it's not the case. I had tried                 `return HttpResponse(render_to_string('sourcing/alert_supplier_change.html', context)` without more success. Gonna continue digging ...

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution that consists in using `get()` method within my CBV. In it, I evaluate my supplier with `set_incoming_supplier()` that returns a **`context`** or `None`. According to this evaluation, I `render` either the regular template or my alert template.

**ProduitListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):**

```
class ProduitListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):

    model = Produit
    context_object_name = "produits"
    paginate_by = 10
    template_name = 'products/produits.html'
    ordering = ['-mageid', ]

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProduitListView, self).get_context_data(
            *args, **kwargs)
        context['avail_warehouses'] = Warehouse.objects.all()
        context['js_warehouses'] = serialize(
            'json', Warehouse.objects.all(), fields=('code', 'id', ))
        context['title'] = 'Produits'
        return context

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        supplier_pk = self.kwargs.get('pk', None)
        if supplier_pk:
            context = set_incoming_supplier(self.request, supplier_pk)
            if context:
                return render(request, 'sourcing/alert_supplier_change.html', context)
        return super().get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

**set_incoming_supplier()**

```
def set_incoming_supplier(request, pk):
    supplier = Supplier.objects.filter(pk=pk).first()
    supp = SupplierSerializer(instance=supplier).data
    rs = request.session
    if 'income' in rs:
        if 'cur_supplier' in rs['income']:
            prev_supplier = rs['income']['cur_supplier']
            if supp != prev_supplier:
                return {'prev_supplier': prev_supplier, 'cur_supplier': supp}
    rs['income'] = {'cur_supplier': supp}
```

Maybe not the best way but it works well.